# Displaying content type as a field in a page

Tags: entities, 8

I am stuck with this architectural design for a client of mine. I am trying to create a testimonial block in 3 different pages, that client can pick any testimonial and I will create simple bootstrap carousel system for that.

So I created a custom content type name testimonial which has 3 fields, body, client name, and client title. This is the point I get stuck, I have no clue what would be the next? I tried to create that block via views slideshow but then client won't be to pick testimonials that they want, it will display all the testimonials.

I wonder if there is a way that I can add this content type as a field at that page? Or am I going to create a custom page(as a module) and create a custom field for this testimonial content type? If I have to do so, is there anyone who encountered this and completed something like this, can direct me to a sample of this?

Comment: Sorry, but your Q is unclear to me. `but then client won't be to pick testimonials that they want` Are there different types/categories of testimonals? like you have different products? or what?

Comment: @NoSssweat I take the OP is saying the view shows all the nodes without making possible to pickup one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom block type "Testimonial slideshow" or so (Accessible through local tasks on the block overview page), add a reference field and allow nodes of your given type. Set the cardinality to exactly 3.

Then you can create a block of that type and select 3 testimonials (with select or autocomplete, depending on what you configure on manage display).

That's it, now you just have to implement the necessary templates to show it as a slideshow.